# Image sizes in detail page

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, product-view, category-products

In my product detail page, fotorama slider images are not the size I expected. I tried using `view.xml` inside my theme and tried using fallback `view.xml`. I'm using Blank theme as parent.

I need to change image sizes(in this case increase the sizes) as I wish. I cant find which image size to change inside `view.xml` file. I've included two images, one with how I get the images and other one showing chrome inspector that Im getting some inline file sizes (261px for this), which I cant find inside `view.xml` for any image size.

Can please somebody help me?

Comment: share your web URl and what you want o do with image , please make little clear

Comment: @ManojDeswal I need to change image sizes(in this case increase the sizes) as I wish. I cant find which image to to change size inside `view.xml` file. Images I get is too small. I need to increase the size on main image and according to that also change image sizes of slider. can you help please?

Comment: need to debug , share your web URL

Comment: I'm still developing locally. can you tell me how can I use image sizes with view.xml and what image sizes i should change to increase size of  above scenario?

Answer (score 4):

To change Size of **product images** and other **listing page images** or **related item image**

Edit your `view.xml` at below location in your extended theme

```
/app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/etc/view.xml
```

Now add following codes for respective images

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <!-- /**  * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.  * See COPYING.txt for license details.  */
--> <view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">

            <!--size changes for product page image -->
            <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image"/>
            <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
                <width>1000</width>
                <height>1500</height> 
            </image>


            <!--size change listing -->
            <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>300</width>
                <height>450</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_grid-1" type="small_image">
                <width>300</width>
                <height>450</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
                <width>300</width>
                <height>450</height>
            </image>


            <!--size changes for related & upsell-->

            <image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>360</height>
            </image>

            <image id="upsell_products_list" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>360</height>
            </image>

        </images>
    </media>

</view>
```

**Set size as per your ratio of your images**

Example: **your original image size is 1600px wide and 2400px in height** , So set image size in same ratio,  you can keep same or for smaller like 1000 * 1500.

After that run following commands if you are in **developer mode**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

or if your are in **production mode** then run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Comment: many many thanks. I will try and get back to you.

Comment: let me know if any problem ...

Comment: Hi, im still getting the same result. main image is sized 261x261px.

Comment: what is image size you are using , and try creating new product ... take a image 1000 wide and 1500 in height then check does new product have same problem

Comment: Hi, it seems like image is rendered using correct size, but some javascript code is affecting the final image size. like in the image i mentioned above. any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Well need to debug if you can make it live on some demo url ..

Comment: I can send you page source or gallery.phtml file. i think js code is from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65950/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-joey).

Comment: okay, i'll post paste files there